# How to derive the gradient of RNN and what is the definition of Loss function in this graph?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I am reading [Deep Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/rnn.html#pf8) and I am not able to follow the gradient derivation of RNN.

The graph of RNN is like this:
[image: Graph]

The updating equations are as follow:
[image: Equations]

The loss function is:
[image: Loss]

And the derivation of gradient is like this:
[image: Derivation]

I am confused by equation 10.18. 
What is the function of loss here and why this holds:
[image: gradient]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by this :[Softmax and the negative log-likelihood](https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2017/08/13/softmax-and-the-negative-log-likelihood/#nll)

I write my own Softmax function as:
$$\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}=\frac{e^{o_i^{(t)}}}{\sum_j{e^{o_j^{(t)}}}}$$
and it's derivative with respect to $o_i^{(t)}$:

$$\frac{\partial{\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}}} {\partial{o_i^{(t)}}} =\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}(1-\widehat{y}_i^{(t)})$$

My negative log-likelihood is written as:
$$L^{(t)}=-\sum_{i}\log{\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}}$$
and it's derivative with respect to $\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}$:

$$\frac{\partial{L^{(t)}}}{\partial{\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}}}=-\frac{1}{\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}}$$

Combining the equations above, I get:

$$\frac{\partial{L^{(t)}}}{\partial{o_i^{(t)}}}=\frac{\partial{L^{(t)}}}{\partial{\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}}} \frac{\partial{\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}}}{\partial{o_i^{(t)}}}=-\frac{1}{\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}}[\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}(1-\widehat{y}_i^{(t)})]=\widehat{y}_i^{(t)}-1 $$

I have two questions now:

1. Is my derivation above correct?
2. If it is, why is there a small difference between my result and the book [*Deep Learning*](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/rnn.html#pf8) :
   $$\textbf{1}_{i=y^{(t)}}$$
   what dose $\textbf{1}_{i=y^{(t)}}$ mean and can it be just a simple 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help:
.
.
.
.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7TWwiIrcJstZjdWTG84VVF1eDA/view

Comment: Hi, Joitandr. Thanks for your answer. I found this helps: https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2017/08/13/softmax-and-the-negative-log-likelihood/#nll